# statistics about old Android applications

Tags: android, google-play, mobile-application, appstats

I have a dataset of 10,000 Android mobile applications (only the name of the app) and I want to get statistics about each application (developer/company name, how many downloads, price, launching date, ratings, and any available public growth/decline stats, etc.). 
I tried looking into the Google Play website but the problem is these apps are old (used in 2011-2012) AND were used in India (not the US, where I am). So, I can't find many of them on the Google Play (https://play.google.com/store?hl=en)

Is there a way (an api for the archive of Android market [Google Play] for example) to get such information?

Here is what I tried so far:

1- Created a gmail account and set the location to India, but I still get the home page of the US Google Play market.

2- looked into many websites like appbrain.com, androlib.com and some other ones but they sometimes not have the apps at all or just say "this app is no longer available in the Google Play"

3- I know that the app name is not a unique identifier and I need to get the package name, but for now the name is enough. I want any app with this name.

I also have non-Android apps, is there a similar way for Blackberry or Symbian (Nokia) markets? But the Android ones are the most important ones. If you can help me with any type of apps, that will be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: https://github.com/egirault/googleplay-api might help.

Comment: Thanks @JonasCz. It was a little involved to get it working. FYI, it gets results from current (not old) Google Play market and you can't change your location. Thanks though! I am using it now.